# How to create multi-part paths with FastAPI

Tags: python, url, path, fastapi

I'm working on a FastAPI application, and I want to create multi-part paths. What I mean by this is I know how to create a path like this for all the REST methods:

```
/api/people/{person_id}
```

but what's a good way to create this:

```
/api/people/{person_id}/accounts/{account_id}
```

I could just keep adding routes in the "people" routes module to create the additional accounts paths, but I feel like there should be a separate "accounts" routes module that could be included in the "people" routes module, and I'm just missing something.

Am I over-thinking this?

Comment: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#another-module-with-apirouter seems to be useful for what you mention

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but look at that documentation it looks like that creates: 

/items/{item_id}

and

/users/{user_id}

What I'm looking for is:

/first_collection/{first_collection_id}/second_collection/{second_collection_id}

Thanks though,
Doug

Comment: will this work for you? `router = APIRouter(prefix='/people/{person_id}/accounts')` then you can do `@router.get('/{account_id}')`? your function can then accept both `person_id` and `account_id` as parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what I have mentioned in the comments, would something like this be of use?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter

app = FastAPI()

people_router = APIRouter(prefix='/people')
account_router = APIRouter(prefix='/{person_id}/accounts')


@people_router.get('/{person_id}')
def get_person_id(person_id: int) -> dict[str, int]:
    return {'person_id': person_id}


@account_router.get('/{account_id}')
def get_account_id(person_id: int, account_id: int) -> dict[str, int]:
    return {'person_id': person_id, 'account_id': account_id}


people_router.include_router(account_router)
app.include_router(people_router, prefix='/api')
```

Comment: Hmmm, that looks interesting. I hadn't thought about adding a path parameter to the APIRouter prefix parameter. I'll give that a try.

Comment: That did work; thanks a lot! I'm going to refactor my code to take advantage of this.